# Corda Notary vault not showing transactions

Tags: corda

I'm trying the obligation cordapp and I did some transactions from Party A to party B, and party B to party C.

When I run `run internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot` on the party A, party B and party C shell, I do see the transactions in their respective vaults. But when I run it on the Notary shell, I don't see anything. I thought I would be able to see something on the Notary's vault. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to ensure that the notary is a validating notary (who is sent entire transactions to validate) rather than a non-validating notary (who is only sent transaction hashes and output indices, to preserve privacy).

Additionally, note that a transaction is only sent to the notary is at least one of the following conditions is satisfied:

1. The transaction contains one or more inputs
2. The transaction has a time-window

If neither of these conditions is satisfied, the transaction will not be sent to the notary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joel. The transaction is a validating notary, I configured it to `true`. It also has one or more inputs, since I transferred an obligation from PartyB to PartyC, and from partyA to partyC. It still didnt show up in its vault by running the command `run internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot`

Comment: I don't know what to say. It's working on my machine.

Comment: directly from the git repo?